# How to see Items in a ListBox Longer than the width of the control

Tags: listbox, vb.net-2010, listbox-control

I have a List Box which have certain dimentions
Some of the Items are loger than the width of the ListBox control.
When I pass the mouse over these Items I want to see all the name.
I'm using vb.net

Comment: You mean you'd like a tooltip to show the full text value of the item?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
Private Sub ListBox1_MouseMove (ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs) Handles ListBox1.MouseMove
    Dim ListMousePosition As Point = Me.ListBox1.PointToClient(Me.MousePosition)
    Dim itemIndex As Integer = Me.ListBox1.IndexFromPoint(ListMousePosition)
    If itemIndex > -1 Then
        Dim s As String = Me.ListBox1.Items(itemIndex).ToString()
        Dim g As Graphics = Me.ListBox1.CreateGraphics()
        If g.MeasureString(s, Me.ListBox1.Font).Width > Me.ListBox1.ClientRectangle.Width Then
        Me.ToolTip.SetToolTip(Me.ListBox1, s)
        else
        Me.ToolTip.SetToolTip(Me.ListBox, "")
        End If
        g.Dispose()
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: OK I did manage to play with it. It's fantastic.. even it produse a blinking!!! I can't see why is that!!